# NPM install keeps failing in the same place in when building Docker container on Ubuntu EC2

Tags: shell, docker, ubuntu, jenkins, npm

I've been trying to create some build automation scripts to be ran by a job on my Jenkins server on an Ubuntu EC2 instance. I want the script to remove any loose containers and images, then build the new version of my image and replace the running container. Here's my build script:

```
# Granting superuser
sudo -i

# Initializing Variables
_imagetag=nurenui-v1

# Initializing functions
buildImage()
{    
    docker build -t "$_imagetag" .
}

removeOldImage()
{
    docker rmi $_imagetag
}

pruneImagesAndContainers()
{
    docker container prune --force
    docker image prune --force
}

pruneImagesAndContainers

if [ "$(docker images $_imagetag)" == "" ]; then
    buildImage
else
    removeOldImage
    buildImage
fi
```

There were a few jobs that I ran that worked very well. But for some reason, today, the build keeps failing on NPM install in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install 
COPY . .
RUN npm run build 

FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

NPM install works fine on my machine, but I can't test docker on it because I am still on Win8. If i try to build the docker image inside or outside of jenkins, I always get this:

```
17:30:22 Started by GitHub push by ObsidianTech
17:30:22 Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/UI/NuRenUI
17:30:22 [WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
17:30:22 [WS-CLEANUP] Deferred wipeout is used...
17:30:22 [WS-CLEANUP] Done
17:30:22 using credential ab9c5d12-0a8d-4edb-9be4-83813cf29068
17:30:22 Cloning the remote Git repository
17:30:22 Cloning repository https://github.com/ObsidianTech/NuRenPivot.git
17:30:22  > git init /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/UI/NuRenUI # timeout=10
17:30:22 Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/ObsidianTech/NuRenPivot.git
17:30:22  > git --version # timeout=10
17:30:22 using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
17:30:22  > git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/ObsidianTech/NuRenPivot.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
17:30:23  > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/ObsidianTech/NuRenPivot.git # timeout=10
17:30:23  > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
17:30:23  > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/ObsidianTech/NuRenPivot.git # timeout=10
17:30:23 Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/ObsidianTech/NuRenPivot.git
17:30:23 using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
17:30:23  > git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/ObsidianTech/NuRenPivot.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
17:30:24  > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
17:30:24  > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
17:30:24 Checking out Revision 53e55914222b3f53f173e313d2dc8c7c10746083 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
17:30:24  > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
17:30:24  > git checkout -f 53e55914222b3f53f173e313d2dc8c7c10746083
17:30:24 Commit message: "trying to fix npm issue"
17:30:24  > git rev-list --no-walk b01ea4d30b391f700a0c597a20bbb5ff6e6f552d # timeout=10
17:30:24 [NuRenUI] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins6764800963704352013.sh
17:30:24 + ls
17:30:24 Dockerfile
17:30:24 README.md
17:30:24 babel.config.js
17:30:24 package-lock.json
17:30:24 package.json
17:30:24 public
17:30:24 qaBuild.sh
17:30:24 qaDeploy.sh
17:30:24 src
17:30:24 + chmod 777 ./qaBuild.sh
17:30:24 + chmod 777 ./qaDeploy.sh
17:30:24 + ./qaBuild.sh
17:30:28 Deleted Containers:
17:30:28 9cd52dadac2f379dffc630d01f0ade2069b0a5683a0dce2c2261490529f75db6
17:30:28 
17:30:28 Total reclaimed space: 138.6MB
17:30:28 Deleted Images:
17:30:28 deleted: sha256:0fbd6c6b36a785ecebe8f9ecc971e7645ef209a7a62de4996b773a37bee6b4a4
17:30:28 deleted: sha256:ba7d8f555b9eb7cf15dbda40569efe6171bddeeeaa0deced3816217690943f21
17:30:28 deleted: sha256:0ce9c7023bc64f5798954340ae9b44d9afe231b3e724351059dbd275e9e98c87
17:30:28 deleted: sha256:8b626fa0dcd67eab716ed8999e0fdbfe063c630685f7a77dfb592f15df93198c
17:30:28 
17:30:28 Total reclaimed space: 421.3kB
17:30:28 ./qaBuild.sh: 23: [: REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
17:30:28 nurenui-v1          latest              c6fd05d82c12        13 hours ago        43.7MB: unexpected operator
17:30:28 Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to remove repository reference "nurenui-v1" (must force) - container e300a467c2e0 is using its referenced image c6fd05d82c12
17:30:29 Sending build context to Docker daemon  67.87MB

17:30:29 Step 1/10 : FROM node:latest as build-stage
17:30:29  ---> 502d06d3bfdf
17:30:29 Step 2/10 : WORKDIR /app
17:30:29  ---> Running in d12805e29d2e
17:30:30 Removing intermediate container d12805e29d2e
17:30:30  ---> 4f573ab1b889
17:30:30 Step 3/10 : COPY package*.json ./
17:30:30  ---> 9fc9cb7ed731
17:30:30 Step 4/10 : RUN npm install
17:30:30  ---> Running in 70fe3d18ecc4
17:31:03 
17:31:03 > yorkie@2.0.0 install /app/node_modules/yorkie
17:31:03 > node bin/install.js
17:31:03 
17:31:03 [91m
17:31:03 [0mThe command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1
17:31:05 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
17:31:05 Finished: FAILURE
```

I keep getting some kind of error about yorkie before it fails. I have no idea why this is happening or how to fix it.

Edit: package.json

```
{
  "name": "nurenpivot",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.6",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.4",
    "vuex": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Comment: There were several relevant errors in your logs that I would be referencing in a possible answer. Why did you edit the question to remove them?

Comment: Sorry, I edited them back in.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your logs (before you deleted them from the original question), I could see that you have several errors in your build script way before the step in the `Dockerfile` where you do the `npm install`. For example, `sudo` was failing, the test with `[` was also failing, to mention some.

This build script is actually very badly written, as it never checks for errors. Any problem would be simply ignored. When an important command can fail, you have to check the return code (`$?`) to be equal to zero, before you proceed. Another option you have is to stop on any error using `set -e` at the very beginning of the script.

As for the other errors, there's not enough information to help you. Please update the question with the complete logs, as they were before (just remove the sensitive parts) and with the contents of your `package.json`. It's also needed to check the npm and nodejs version running on Jenkins and on your machine, to check if they match.

---

**Edit after logs were re-added to the question:**

Looking at these lines of your logs:

```
17:30:28 ./qaBuild.sh: 23: [: REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
17:30:28 nurenui-v1          latest              c6fd05d82c12        13 hours ago        43.7MB: unexpected operator
17:30:28 Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to remove repository reference "nurenui-v1" (must force) - container e300a467c2e0 is using its referenced image c6fd05d82c12
```

It became clear that you are using the raw output from the command `docker images $_imagetag`, which is definitely **not** what you want. If you try this command, you'll see that the output contains a lot of other information, like a header, size, tag, etc. Even if the image doesn't exist, it outputs the header line. It's literally what the logs are telling you, something like this:

```
REPOSITORY      TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
nurenui-v1      latest    c6fd05d82c12   13 hours ago   43.7MB
```

To do that check, you have to add `-q` to the command. This way it won't output anything if the image is not found. Change that line to look like this:

```
if [ -n "$(docker images -q $_imagetag)" ]; then
    removeOldImage
fi

buildImage
```

... but this is not the only problem you have. I can also see a container using that image... and I didn't even check the package.json.

Comment: Yeah, first ever shell script so I expected as much. I added the previous log and the package.json. I have no idea what ($?) is so I'll look that up.

Comment: @ChrisJames, the `$?` automatic variable holds the exit code of the previous command you run. If equals to `0` it was successful, anything else denotes a failure.  To avoid checking this all the time, it's a common practice to chain dependent commands with `&&` so the first failure breaks the chain, but I'm not exactly sure what you want to achieve.